# BootStrap4 font color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap and I'm using my knowledge of css3 when you want to change the color of a font you give a class or id to the section or whatever to target it and then change your font. I'm using a pre built navBar and trying to do the same but it isn't working. Can someone help me with not only the answer but the explanation of how to target my links all the top to change to WHITE the font color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">



        <title>Richard Jimenez Portfolio</title>

          <style type="text/css">
              #myList{
                  font:white;
              }


          </style>

      </head>

    <body>   

    <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyApp</a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="myList">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Experience</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resume</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </header>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to be more specific on elements you are targeting

```
#myList a {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Do you have notice the change on the css property ? It's not "font" but "color". In the example i give you, links "Home", "Experience", "Projects", "Resume" & "Contact" become white ;)